# How to install brew on a Mac with a normal Administrator User?

Tags: homebrew

I want to install brew:
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` (taken from current website).

This gives me the following error:
`Don't run this as root!`

I'm confused, because the user is NOT root, I'm logged in as normal default user with administration rights.

Any help?

Comment: Try `id -Gn YOURUSERNAME` and see if `admin` group is listed.

Comment: Your `$UID`  appears to be `0`, which is `root`. Are you trying to run it with `sudo`?

Comment: No, i run it without sudo (otherwise the official website would recommend that)

Comment: What is the output of `echo $UID`?

Comment: @bfontaine i will check later. Why? There is nothing mentioned on the brew website that there are some required variables to be set in the shell.

Comment: @bfontaine : when I enter `echo $UID` it returns `501`

Comment: The **homebrew** installation script only prints the line saying not to run as root at one single place, immediately after checking if your `$UID` is zero. So you must have been root when you last ran it. Try `echo $UID` to ensure it is 501 then try running the **homebrew** installation again.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to not being able to install brew as root. Therefore, we need to create a new user and perform the installation processes through that user.

Open the Terminal and run the following command to create a new user account:

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

Replace username with the name of the user you want to create.

After running the command, the system will ask you to set a password and enter the user's name, surname, and other information. Complete these steps.

Use the following command to give the new user the necessary permissions to perform operations:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

This will ensure that the new user is added to the sudo group, allowing them to perform operations with sudo privileges.
To switch to the new user, use the command `su newuser`.

**INSTALL BREW**

The official website of Brew offers a pre-build script to install download and install Homebrew using the command line on any available Linux such as CentOS, RHEL, OpenSUSE, Linux Mint, Kali, MX Linux, POP!OS, and others.

Here is the command, just run it-

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

To run the brew command after installation, we need to add it to our system path...

```
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> ~/.bashrc

eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

If you receive an error with the above command, edit the .bashrc path. If you receive a permission error, grant your permission with `sudo chmod 777 ~/.bashrc`

Make sure you are in the newly created user account and in the root directory during all of these processes.